# How to compile KeePassX 0.4 under Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: 18.04, compiling, qt

Can someone download the source code and tell me how to compile KeePassX 0.4 for Ubuntu? I have no clue about programming! No matter what I paste into the terminal I get nothing. Please, help me someone, I beg you, Anonimus :)

https://www.keepassx.org/downloads/0-4

Thanks!

Comment: If you are simply looking to implement the keepassx system of password control, you could install keepassx on Ubuntu with `sudo apt install keepassx`, or `keepassxc` or `keepass2`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After you download the source (currently the latest version of the 0.4 series is 0.4.4).

**Extract the Tarball**

```
tar -xvf keepassx-0.4.4.tar.gz
```

**Fix the Source**

The build process currently fails as standard in Ubuntu 18.04 due to a missing include directive. This needs to be added as follows:

1. Open the source file `keepassx/src/lib/random.cpp` using a text editor.
2. Add the line `#include <unistd.h>` immediately before the line `#include <QCryptographicHash>` and save the file.

After editing, the `random.cpp` file should look like:

```
...
#include <unistd.h>
#include <QCryptographicHash>
...
```

**Install the Dependencies**

```
sudo apt install qt4-default libxtst-dev build-essential
```

**Build and Install**

Ensure you are in the root folder of the source (`~/Downloads/keepassx-0.4.4` for example).

```
qmake
make
sudo checkinstall make install
```

KeePassX V0.4.4 should now be available within the launcher.

Comment: By the way using [CheckInstall](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CheckInstall) (`sudo checkinstall make install`) would be better as it creates deb-package of self-compiled application.

Comment: @N0rbert thanks. I wasn't aware of that. I'll update the answer.

Comment: @gsxruk hello is it possible to compile keepassx on Ubuntu 22.04 or compile it on Ubuntu 20.04 but statically (portable version?) I really need it in 22.04